# POSIX sh: How can I read an entire file into a single string using only the shell, while preserving whitespace and newlines in the original file?

Tags: string, shell, posix

Before everyone freaks out and says this a duplicate, I would like to point out that while there are many questions about reading a file line by line, none that I've found are about storing an entire file into a single variable. Rather, most of the questions seem to be about performing some sort of operation on each line as they are being read in. As a example, consider the below:

```
#!/bin/sh

while IFS='' read -r line || [ -n "$line" ]; do
    echo "$line"
done < file
```

I can't seem to implement this for my specific purpose. When I do the below:

```
#!/bin/sh

newline='
'

string=''
while IFS='' read -r line || [ -n "$line" ]; do
    string="$string""$line""$newline"
done < file

echo "$string"
```

I almost get there, but now there is an extra newline at the end, and my string is not equal to my file. I've played with this for quite awhile, and I can't seem to read in the file such that my resulting string is completely identical to my file.

Comment: Instead of `echo "$string"`, perhaps you want `printf '%s' "$string"`, to avoid the extra newline added by `echo`.

Comment: A point of style: `string="$string$line$newline"` or `string="${string}${line}${newline}"` seems much cleaner than using extra `"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're unconditionally adding a newline, with the `string="$string""$line""$newline"` assignment.

`read` returns true as long as it successfully reads a line, including a newline. Checking if `$line` contains anything deals with the possible final line fragment. But when you process it, you need to *not* add the newline since it wasn't there to begin with. As long as there's no final line fragment, your script works fine.

It's probably easiest to fix by moving the `[ -n "$line" ]` test outside the loop:

```
#!/bin/sh
newline='
'
string=
while IFS= read -r line; do
    string="$string$line$newline"
done < "$1"
if [ "$line" ]; then
    string="$string$line"
fi

echo "<$string>"       # markers for clarity
```

Of course it might also be that the input file only has complete lines, and the extra newline is the one that `echo` prints. Use `printf "%s" "$string"` to print just the contents of the variable, without a newline or anything else. Some shells have `echo -n` to inhibit the final newline, but that's nonstandard.